# Check the maximum usage of kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to check the maximum and average of kubernetes Pod. and I  tried to find it but cannot get any relevant information. Also, I checked the Lens (third-party software) but only get the current usage and it only shows usage, limit for past 1 hour.

How to find the maximum usage of Pod?

Comment: You need to measure it over time and calculate the average. Prometheus and co can help you with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
kubectl describe quota
```

Or within a different namespace:

```
kubectl describe quota --namespace=<your-namespace>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the ressources Limits in your config creation yaml file, it will takes by default those values :

> Create the Pod. The output shows that the Pod's container has a memory
> request of 256 MiB and a memory limit of 512 MiB. These are the
> default values specified by the LimitRange

You have more infos [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/#:%7E:text=Create%20the%20Pod.&text=The%20output%20shows%20that%20the,values%20specified%20by%20the%20LimitRange.)

You have an article [here](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-limits-requests/#:%7E:text=All%20pod%20containers%20have%20to,be%20higher%20than%202%20GiB.), if you want to specify your pods limit manually.

PS: if you enable promotheus in your Lens, you can visualize your different metrics (pods usage and limits for the cpu, memory, network, and filessytem)